# Are there any gems moving files between windows or/and between windows and linux?

Tags: ruby

I am not sure which ruby gems that I can use to move files between windows or between windows and linux? SCP -- I think it's just for Linux system. Am I right?

Comment: scp is only linux that I know, ftp is a protocol that works across both platforms but it is not secure

Comment: No, I haven never done that before setting up an SSH on Windows.

Comment: Why use a Gem?  Linux servers should all support SMBFS.  Mount the windows folder as a share on the linux server and copy the files across using normal file system tools.